# Binary decision boundary requiring 2 hidden layers in neural network with limited neurons

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, classification, hyperparameter, topologies

I just started learning about neural networks and was wondering what a neural network with 2 hidden layers is able to express over a neural network with just 1 hidden layer (where number of neurons are limited). Specifically, I am trying to come up with an binary classification example with a decision boundary that can be expressed with 2 hidden layers but not one (assuming input is a point in the 2D space, ReLU activation for the hidden layers, and sigmoid activation for the output). The 1-layer network has 4 hidden neurons in its layer while the 2-layer network has 2 neurons each layer, so still 4 hidden neurons total. I've tried looking at concentric circles, enclosed shapes, and nonlinear boundaries but have no luck so far.

What is an example of a binary decision boundary that 2 hidden layers (2 neurons each layer) are able to capture but 1 hidden layer (4 neurons) isn't? Is this even possible?

Update: I edited my question to a limited number of neurons as that the universal approximation theorem does not apply.

Comment: Welcome to CV! Please add the [tag:self-study] tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Answer (score 2):

Neural networks with one hidden layer are universal approximators (given some constraints), so you won't find such a class of functions. See [Does the universal approximation theorem apply to ReLu?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/525679/60613)

Comment: I believe that universal approximation theorem only holds for a large amount of neurons in the 1 hidden layer. What about if the 1 hidden layer network had 4 neurons in the hidden layer and the 2 layer network had 2 neurons each layer (so still 4 hidden neurons total)?

Comment: @ReginaDea in general it's a good idea to ask a new question in this case, otherwise people could keep narrowing down their question indefinitely.